# Simple forum problems - CSS and jQuery likely culprits for IE and FF incompatibility

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC website. I have a CSS problem.
In the website I have [a very simple forum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6CEZ.png). You can [expand messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWmAa.png) by clicking on their title, and then you can [reply to a message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3ArV.png) from within the message. These screen shots are from Chrome. However, when I load it up in IE or FF, the last bit under the reply form [disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EjkX.png) (you can see it for half a sec and then it vanishes).

**EDIT**: Here's a [link](http://www.dlaglagim.com/Home/Forum/0) to a working example.

Here is the source code:

The HTML (with ASP.NET) function inside:

```
<div class="postNewMessageContainer">
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Forum", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "postMessageForm" }))
           { %>
            <fieldset class="commentFieldset">
                <legend class="addCommentBtn">הוסף הודעה</legend>

                <div class="addCommentBox">
                        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageSubject)  %>          
                        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.messageSubject, new { @class = "required"})%>  

                        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageComposer)  %>    
                        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.messageComposer, new { @class = "required"})%>      

                        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageContents)  %> 
                        <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.newMessage.messageContents, new { @class = "required"})%>

                        <input type="hidden" name="newMessage.parentMessageID" value="0" />

                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="שלח"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>


        <%} %>
    </div> <%-- postNewMessageContainer --%>

    <%-- display all forum messages --%>
    <div class="forumContainer">
    <% foreach (var completeParentMessage in Model.CompleteForumMessages.Where(a=>a.parentMsg.isActive == true))
       {%>
        <div class="forumMessageContainer userType<%=Html.Encode(completeParentMessage.parentMsg.MessageAuthorType)%>" 
        id="forumMessage<%=Html.Encode(completeParentMessage.parentMsg.MessageID)%>">
            <div class="msgHeader">    
                    <span class="forumMsgSubject"><%=completeParentMessage.parentMsg.MessageSubject%></span>
                    <span class="forumMsgComposer"><%=completeParentMessage.parentMsg.MessageComposerName%></span>
                    <span class="forumMsgDate"><%=completeParentMessage.parentMsg.MessageDate.Value.ToString()%></span>
            </div>
            <div class="msgContents">
                    <span class="forumMsgText"><%=completeParentMessage.parentMsg.MessageContents%></span>


                    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Forum", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "postMessageForm" }))
                       { %>
                        <fieldset class="commentFieldset">
                            <legend class="addCommentBtn">הוסף תגובה</legend>

                            <div class="addCommentBox">

                                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageSubject)  %> 
                                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.messageSubject, new { @class = "required" })%>  

                                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageComposer)  %> 
                                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.messageComposer, new { @class = "required" })%>      

                                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageContents)  %> 
                                    <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.newMessage.messageContents, new { @class = "required" })%>

                                    <input name="newMessage.parentMessageID" type="hidden" 
                                    value="<%=completeParentMessage.parentMsg.MessageID %>" />

                                <div>
                                    <input type="submit" value="שלח"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>


                    <%} %>

            </div>
       </div> 

       <%-- display all responses to current message in loop --%>                     
       <% foreach (var childMessage in completeParentMessage.childMsgs)
          { %>
            <div class="forumSubmessageContainer userType<%=Html.Encode(childMessage.MessageAuthorType)%>" 
            id="forumMessage<%=Html.Encode(childMessage.MessageID)%>">
                <div class="msgHeader">    
                        <span class="forumMsgSubject"><%=childMessage.MessageSubject%></span>
                        <span class="forumMsgComposer"><%=childMessage.MessageComposerName%></span>
                        <span class="forumMsgDate"><%=childMessage.MessageDate.ToString()%></span>
                </div>
                <div class="msgContents">
                        <span class="forumMsgText"><%=childMessage.MessageContents%></span>

                       <% using (Html.BeginForm("Forum", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "postMessageForm" }))
                       { %>
                        <fieldset class="commentFieldset">
                            <legend class="addCommentBtn">הוסף תגובה</legend>

                            <div class="addCommentBox">

                                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageSubject)  %> 
                                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.messageSubject, new { @class = "required" })%>  

                                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageComposer)  %> 
                                    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.newMessage.messageComposer, new { @class = "required" })%>      

                                    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.newMessage.messageContents)  %> 
                                    <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.newMessage.messageContents, new { @class = "required" })%>

                                    <input name="newMessage.parentMessageID" type="hidden" 
                                    value="<%=completeParentMessage.parentMsg.MessageID %>" />

                                <div>
                                    <input type="submit" value="שלח"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>


                    <%} %>

                </div> <%-- /msgContents --%>
            </div> <%-- /forumSubmessageContainer --%>

          <%} %>

       <%} %>

    </div> <%-- /forumContainer --%>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        $(".msgContents").hide();
        $(".msgHeader").click(function() {
            var div = $(this).next("div");
            if (div.is(":hidden")) {
                div.slideDown();
            } else {
                div.slideUp();
            }
        });

        $(".addCommentBox").hide();
        $(".addCommentBtn").click(function() {
            var div = $(this).next("div");
            if (div.is(":hidden")) {
                div.slideDown();
            } else {
                div.slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
    /* ========== Forum ========== */

.forumMessageContainer , .forumSubmessageContainer
{
 margin-top: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
 padding-right: 4px;
 font-size: 15px;
 height: 100%;
}

.forumMessageContainer 
{
 background-color:#CCBBDD;
}

.forumSubmessageContainer
{
 background-color:#CCBBDD; /*#CCCCDD;*/
}

.userType1
{
 background-color: #9966CC;
 color: White;
}

.commentFieldset
{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 margin: 2em;
}

.addCommentBox
{

}

.msgHeader .forumMsgSubject
{
 float:right;
}

.msgHeader:hover, .addCommentBtn:hover
{
 cursor: pointer;
}

.msgHeader .forumMsgDate
{
 float:left;
 padding-left: 5px;
}

.msgHeader .forumMsgComposer
{
 padding-right: 5%;
 font-weight:bold; 
}


.forumSubmessageContainer
{
margin-right:3%;
}

.ForumBackNext
{
 padding-top: 10px;
 text-align:center;
}

#newMessage_messageContents
{
 height:150px;
 width:350px;


}

#newMessage_messageSubject, #newMessage_messageComposerName
{
 width:350px;
}



.deleteForumMsg
{
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 float: left;
}
```

I would appreciate all and any help on the matter.

Also - in IE the forum "titles" (the message title, composer name and date) and new message form [look really bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbW6E.png). So perhaps it could provide further insight into understanding the problem. And if someone has a solution for that as well - I'd really really appreciate it :-)

Thank you all very much!

Comment: It's quite difficult to debug JavaScript (which runs client side) with only server-side code available. Can you post your generated HTML (without the .NET code) or - even better - post a link to a working example.

Comment: Certainly:

http://www.dlaglagim.com/Home/Forum/0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, ok. I believe what you are seeing here are [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).

The easiest solution would probably be to put a padding on the form instead of the margin on the fieldset.